# Javascript to change text of a blank option tag

Tags: javascript

I am fairly new to javascript and have tried to work this out on my own, but I am new to some the objects and properties. I believe that the code I have below would work for changing "all" "option" text in the document, but I need it to only change the text value of empty option tags eg; `<option></option>`, to `<option>Choose One</option>`. I would like it to do this on page load, as the page is generated dynamically by asp.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeEmpty(){
      document.getElementByTagName('option')options[0].text='Choose One';
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: @Bruno, That is *INCORRECT*.

Comment: @epascarello Sorry. Thanks for the correction. In fact there is also a missing "s" in getElementByTagName. It should be `document.getElementsByTagName('option')[0].text = 'Choose One';`

Answer (score 2):

If it is going to be the first option on the page for one select it would be

```
document.getElementsByTagName('option')[0].text='Choose One';
```

It would be better to specify the element so if someone in the future adds a select before it, it will not matter.

```
document.getElementById("MyId").getElementsByTagName('option')[0].text='Choose One';
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"I need it to only change the text value of empty option tags..."*

Your syntax is invalid, so I'm not sure why you think it would change all `option` elements.

But what you can do is simply iterate them, and test the text content.

```
var opts = document.getElementsByTagName('option');

for (var i = 0, len = opts.length; i < len; i++) 
    if (opts[i].text === "")
        opts[i].text = "Choose One";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to change all `<option>`s without content, you can use this code

```
function changeEmpty(){
  var els = document.querySelectorAll( 'option' );

  for ( var i=els.length; i--; ) {
    if ( els.innerHTML.trim() == '' ) {
      els.innerHTML = 'choose one';
    }
  }
}
```

Assuming that the empty `<option>`s will always be the first within each `<select>` tag, change to

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll( 'select > option' );
```

to save some computations.

**EDIT**

`querySelectorAll()` is supported on all modern browsers, but not in IE7 and previous versions! See [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector).

Comment: And you should note that not all browsers support querySelector.